# Create linewidth spaced three columned table with column alignment

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm writing a two columned article:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aps, prb, twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
```

I would like to include a table which is as long as `1.\linewidth`. The table should consist of three columns, the first two are aligned to the left and the last column should be aligned to the right. The last column should also be at the end of `1.\linewidth`.

I have the following code but it is very unsatisfying. This is because I have to manually tune the size of the first two columns in order to have the final column aligned to the end of `1.\linewidth`.

```
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{1.\linewidth}{p{.3\linewidth} p{.3\linewidth} r}
  \hline
  Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
  \hline
  Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
            & each        & 0.01       \\
  Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
  Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
  Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

What would be the correct approach to this problem? Am I correct in using `tabularx` or would you advise something else?

Comment: Don't stretch the table, it just makes it harder to read. If you do use `tabularx` you need to use `X` columns to denote the columns of variable width, but that is intended for changing the line breaking of paragraphs, it's not suitable for numeric tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use `tabular*`; I present two implementations, one with `\hline` and the other one with the very useful package `booktabs` and its features. With `revtex4-1`, this package needs some kick.

```
\documentclass[10pt, aps, prb, twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{tabularx,array,booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

% the following code is for making the booktabs example work
\AtBeginDocument{
  \heavyrulewidth=.08em
  \lightrulewidth=.05em
  \cmidrulewidth=.03em
  \belowrulesep=.65ex
  \belowbottomsep=0pt
  \aboverulesep=.4ex
  \abovetopsep=0pt
  \cmidrulesep=\doublerulesep
  \cmidrulekern=.5em
  \defaultaddspace=.5em
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llr}
\hline
  Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\hline
  Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
            & each        & 0.01       \\
  Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
  Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
  Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}

\lipsum[2]

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llr}
\toprule
  Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\midrule
  Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
            & each        & 0.01       \\
  Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
  Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
  Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would simply typeset the table at its natural width:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\toprule
  Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\midrule
  Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
            & each        & 0.01       \\
  Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
  Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
  Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```